# Buscar en la base de datos

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas tengo un programa en el que busco a un usuario que se encuentra en la base de datos, hasta aqui todo bien porque lo busca y lo encuentra pero si el usuario no esta en la base de datos no me llega ningun error sino que me sale el mismo mensaje de que lo ha encontrado. ¿Como puedo hacer para que me mande un mensaje de error en caso de no tener el usuario registrado en mi base de datos?
Aqui mi codigo:

public void buscarCliente(){

```
   Connection miConexion;
    Statement st;
    try {    
        miConexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fastfoodcompany", "root", "quepasachavales3");
        st=miConexion.createStatement();

        nombre=bajacliente.getTxtNombre().getText();
        apellido1=bajacliente.getTxtSegundoApellido().getText();
        apellido2=bajacliente.getTxtSegundoApellido().getText();

        if (true) {
             String query="SELECT Nombre, Appelido1, Apellido2 FROM clientes WHERE  Nombre= '"+ nombre +"' AND Appelido1 = '"+ apellido1 +"' AND Apellido2 = '"+ apellido2 +"'";

        st.executeQuery(query);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El cliente ha sido encontrado");

       } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El cliente no ha sido encontrado");
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(bdFFC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El cliente no ha sido encontrado"+ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (true) { ` eso siempre se va a cumplir porque true siempre sera true

Comment: El `executeQuery` te devuelve un `ResultSet` con los resultados del SQL. Eso es lo que debes revisar para ver qué es lo que te devuelve la BD, en tu código haces la consulta pero no compruebas el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Hay varias formas de saber si una consulta trajo filas o no. Cuando una consulta es ejecutada, es devuelto un objeto `ResultSet` y conviene aplicar algún método de ese objeto para saber si hay filas en la consulta.

Quizá el mejor método a usar es [**`isBeforeFirst()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst--) el cual:

> Devuelve verdadero si el cursor está antes de la primera fila; falso
>   si el cursor está en cualquier otra posición o el conjunto de
>   resultados no contiene filas.

En el código yo hago la evaluación con un operador ternario, asignando al mismo tiempo un texto a la variable `msgOut`, la cual usamos luego para mostrar. De ese modo quitamos verbosidad a tu código.

Me he permito hacer otras mejoras significativas porque aportan seguridad al código. Tus consultas son vulnerables a ataques de inyección SQL. Toda consulta que maneje datos provenientes del exterior (que no estén declaradas dentro del código mismo) deben ser protegidas mediante consultas preparadas, porque un usuario mal intencionado puede manipular esos datos para ejecutar otro tipo de consultas peligrosas. (Puedes leer [este artículo, en castellano](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/jdbc-prepared-statement-y-su-manejo/), sobre cómo se aplican las consultas preparadas en Java y cuál es su utilidad).

Nada más.

Aquí te dejo el código corregido. Si hay alguna duda lo puedes decir en comentarios. Espero te sirva.

```
public void buscarCliente(){

   Connection miConexion;
    try {    
        miConexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fastfoodcompany", "root", "quepasachavales3");
        st=miConexion.createStatement();

        nombre=bajacliente.getTxtNombre().getText();
        apellido1=bajacliente.getTxtSegundoApellido().getText();
        apellido2=bajacliente.getTxtSegundoApellido().getText();

        String query="SELECT Nombre, Appelido1, Apellido2 FROM clientes WHERE  Nombre= ? AND Appelido1 = ? AND Apellido2 = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps= miConexion.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, nombre);
        ps.setString(2, apellido1);
        ps.setString(3, apellido2);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        String msgOut= ( rs.isBeforeFirst() )  ?  "El cliente ha sido encontrado" :  "El cliente NO ha sido encontrado"; 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msgOut);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(bdFFC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El cliente no ha sido encontrado"+ex);
    }
}
```

> #### OBSERVACIÓN
>
> He visto que tienes una columna llamada `Appelido1` y otra llamada
>   `Apellido2` ... ¿Es eso normal o es un error al escribir la pregunta?